# How to use .htaccess URL masquerading technology

Tags: .htaccess

Basically, I was wondering if I could take a url like:

http://tai.tskynet.com/?id=book

and rewrite it to

http://tai.tskynet.com/book/

http://tai.tskynet.com/book

like a "fake" folder.

What should I write?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make sure that your rewrite_module and dir_module is enabled in apache. Then check your httpd.conf file to make sure that these lines exist:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
```

Then set the value for `DirectoryIndex` to include the target file (index.php as example)

```
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.php ...
</IfModule>
```

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets|uploads|cloudfront\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This would forward your URI values to the target file [index.php] then process it there. 
In the example, `robots\.txt|assets|uploads|cloudfront\.php` will not be forwarded to index.php and instead will be treated as normal directory requests.